# Webflux how to handle error and return when parameter in request is needed

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I can handle error and return in a basic way as this:

```
    public Mono<Response> serviceFunction(Mono<Request> requestMono) {
        return requestMono.map(req -> {
            try {
                List<String> result = handle(req);
                if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
                    return new BadResponse("no record", req.getLogId());
                }
                return new GoodReponse(result, req.getLogId());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return new BadResponse(e.getMessage(), req.getLogId());
            }
        });
    }
```

But things can get messy when multiple `BadResponse` occur here and there in a more completed case. So I want to collect errors and then return in this way:

```
    public Mono<Response> serviceFunction(Mono<Request> requestMono) {
        return requestMono.flatMap(req -> {
            try {
                List<String> result = handle(req);
                if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
                    return Mono.error(new NoRecordError("no records"));
                }
                return Mono.just(new GoodReponse(result));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return Mono.error(e);
            }
        }).onErrorReturn(NoRecordError.class, new BadResponse("no record", logId))  // how to get logId from request?
          .onErrorReturn(JsonProcessingException.class, new BadResponse(e.getMessage(), logId))// how to get logId from request?
    }
```

Then in `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResume`, a bean is returned with value contained in `requestMono`,  how to get that value? I tried `zipWhen` or `zipWith`, then `onErrorXxx` consumes a `Tuple` and returns one too -- making things unnecessarily complicated. Thanks.

Comment: either move all of it inside the `flatMap`, or create own type of Exception with `logId` field